# EntityMetadata Wrapper get relation

Tags: views, theming

I'm trying to theme a field in a complex view that was setup by someone else.

We have three node types: Location, Candidate, Survey
(A location has many candidates, a candidate has 1 survey - but a survey can have more than 1 candidate)

My question is basically, when viewing the Location node, I can get the survey, but not the Candidate:

```
$survey_node = node_load($row->{$field->field_alias});
$survey_wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $survey_node);

$candidate_wrapper = ???
```

**Some background**
When viewing a location node a table view lists candidates across the columns and their survey results.
(The view has been setup by someone else and I am not entirely sure how it has been configured to look this way).

I'm trying to customise the Field that displays the candidate name by overriding the view template.

I've overridden the template, but can't figure out how to traverse the relation and get the data I want

Here's the sticking point, a survey may have more than 1 candidate associated with it - so when traversing from the survey node back to the candidate, how do I make sure that it's the candidate for the electorate?

Comment: Why can't you fetch the candidates directly in Views. It seems very inefficient that in the field template fire off node_load and entity_metadata_wrapper.

Comment: Hi Pontus I'm pretty new to drupal, so if there's another way to do this am happy to learn - the node load is the only way I could figure out how.  
  
By fetch in the view, do you mean add as a field?  
  
If I do that, how do I then access the data from that field from within the theme file?

Comment: Check out the video series Taming the beast so that you have the basics on Views in Drupal http://nodeone.se/sv/node/673 it will help you understand the concepts of contextual filters and relationships.